# D3 function to be called on mouse click (weird behaviour)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was wondering if you could help me out with a doubt I have regarding D3. I have spent all night fixing a bug, and after fixing it I still don't understand what's going on.

Refeer to the following code:

```
svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", window.bboxWidth)
        .attr("height", window.bboxHeight)
        .attr("style", "cursor:crosshair")
        .on("click", addSite())

function addSite() {
    console.log("hue")
}
```

and it's variant with the function declared inline

```
svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", window.bboxWidth)
    .attr("height", window.bboxHeight)
    .attr("style", "cursor:crosshair")
    .on("click", function() {
        console.log("hue")
    })
```

I don't understand why, but if I use the first variant, the code is executed without clicking, and in the second case it works perfectly. I create the svg inside an init function that is called onload() of the body of the HTML.

This gave a headache, because I was trying to use d3.mouse(this) to retrieve the coordinates of the mouse and it was giving me the error "TypeError t is null" (even when using select("svg") instead of *this*. After discovering this I realized that it was giving me such error because the method was being called without having anything initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are not equivalent. the parenthesis after `addSite()` call the addSite function, which means that the return value will be passed as the callback to `.on`, and not the `addSite` function itself!

The same thing would happen in the second snippet if you add `()` after the inline definition: the inline function would be called immediately and its return value (so, nothing) would be passed as callback to `.on`, exactly like your first snippet.

Just pass `addSite` without parenthesis:

```
svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", window.bboxWidth)
        .attr("height", window.bboxHeight)
        .attr("style", "cursor:crosshair")
        .on("click", addSite)  // Don't call it! 

function addSite() {
    console.log("hue")
}
```

Comment: A bit obsolete maybe, but would wrapping the function call to addSite in it's own function make a difference? I.e.  `.on("click", function() { addSite()})`

Comment: That would work, but why do it when you can just pass addSite and get the same thing?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just realized how dumb I was. The thing is that in my original method I needed the parenthesis because my function had a parameter (coordinates). I was passing 'd3.mouse(this)' as parameter.

Comment: Then you can use a wrapper function like @JabbaWook wrote, so that you can pass all the arguments you want to addSite, or you can use `.bind()` to create a partial function `.on("click", addsite.bind(undefined, d3.mouse(this))`

Comment: Actually `.bind` doesn't seem to work with `d3.mouse(this)` (while it works with fixed arguments), so use the wrapper function.